# How to fix MySQL-Connector INSERT Bug?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm trying to get my user id and write it into mysql db.
The problem occurs at the moment when I try to write this data (31-34).  It writes random id into db (2147483647), but i need to write my user id (1003694956919148625). Any ideas?

```py
class MyModal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label="Name"))
        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label="Gender"))
        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label="City"))
        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label="Description", style=discord.InputTextStyle.long))

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        id = interaction.user.id
        print(id)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO users (id, name, gender, city, description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (id, self.children[0].value, self.children[1].value, self.children[2].value, self.children[3].value)
        )
        connection.commit()
```

In console print id is correct
But in db - it isn't

I tried to print id in console - it works
I tried to save id in MySQL - in not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to change the datatypes of all columns to VARCHAR and everything will be fixed

```html
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN id VARCHAR(255);
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN name VARCHAR(255);
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN gender VARCHAR(255);
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN city VARCHAR(255);
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN description VARCHAR(255);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which type are you using for the id in the db?

I recommend you to store it in an varchar or text column. Otherside, there can be problems with the type or overflow of the value

Comment: id: int
name: varchar
gender: varchar
city: varchar
description: text